# swift App using cocoapod fails to launch after 20.00s

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I created a default one view swift project and added 11 libraries in the Podfile.
I can run the app from inside xcode, but the app fails to run when I run it from the phone directly with this stack:

> Incident Identifier: 3EB8A44E-8F2C-407A-AE7B-A314E62AC61B
>   CrashReporter Key:   d8ab2628e36e1c5ef60c63f217d734d62950b336 Hardware
>   Model:      iPhone5,2 Process:             testPod [1250] Path:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0F6BFE2A-4FD0-4553-9AB6-CFC5281FE707/testPod.app/testPod
>   Identifier:          com.franck.testPod.testPod Version:             1
>   (1.0) Code Type:           ARM (Native) Parent Process:      launchd
>   [1]
>
> Date/Time:           2016-03-17 10:48:44.44 +0100 Launch Time:
>   2016-03-17 10:48:22.22 +0100 OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
>   Report Version:      105
>
> Exception Type:  00000020 Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
>   Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash) Highlighted by
>   Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information: com.franck.testPod.testPod failed to
>   launch after 20.00s (launchIntent: foreground-interactive)
>
> Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 25.650 (user 25.650, system 0.000),
>   64% CPU  Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.020, 0% CPU
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0: 0   dyld                            0x1fe96e8c __fcntl + 8 1 
>   dyld                              0x1fe96a94 fcntl + 108 2   dyld
>     0x1fe86ff4 ImageLoaderMachO::loadCodeSignature(linkedit_data_command
>   const*, int, unsigned long long, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
>   3   dyld                              0x1fe8b640
>   ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int,
>   unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long
>   long, stat const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, linkedit_data_command
>   const*, encryption_info_command const*, ImageLoader::LinkContext
>   const&) + 244 4   dyld                            0x1fe8651e
>   ImageLoaderMachO::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char
>   const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&,
>   ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 246

Has anyone experienced this before ? I'm using cocoapods-0.39.0.

The Podfile is:

```
target 'testPod' do
  pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField'
  pod 'CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout'
  pod 'Argo'
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
  pod 'Alamofire' 
  pod 'SwiftCarousel'
  pod 'SnapKit'
  pod 'WatchdogInspector'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

Comment: Can you show what your AppDelegate does? Also what your initial ViewController is loading. There's probably some issue in either one of those.

Comment: Nothing, it's the default one. all functions are empty

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm kind of experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @Mustafa Well I put an answer, if you want more info check: https://github.com/artsy/eigen/issues/586

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been automatically fixed by iOS 9.3